# On finding new mathematical constants and patterns

Tags: intuition, constants

How does one go about finding mathematical constants and patterns...

I enjoy playing around on my graphing calculator, typing random functions in trying to find patterns and such and sometimes I'll use mathematical constants in the functions I play around with, how would I know if I came across something of importance such as a new constant or an interesting pattern? I found a function that returned a sequence of prime numbers up to 19 that included the MRB constant, but I do not think that is of any importance and another that returned a sequence of numbers with every number having a repeating decimal after it and in the function the variable (let's say "C") altered the frequency of those numbers with repeating decimals after them. Make "A" be the numbers with repeating decimals and "B" be whole numbers and the pattern would be something like BAABAABAA or AAABAAABAAA etc. depending on what the "C" is.

Comment: These two sites might help:
http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html            and 
http://oeis.org/

Comment: I greatly appreciate it! This website looks like it will help a lot, thanks!

Comment: The more mathematics you learn, the more feeling you will have for whether something you come across is, or isn't, new and/or interesting. So, take lots of math courses, read lots of math books and papers.